# Are the orienteering marches popular in Germany?

Tags: navigation, maps, europe, germany, orienteering

I'm engaged in **orienteering marches**, which differ from **sport orienteering**: there is the time limit, where finishing before time gives no advantage to the participant, and the center is put on the decoding of the map. The map itself is highly transformed - this involves fragmenting, stretching, mirroring, deforming etc.

I've tried to find some information about such orienteering marches in Germany, but found only information about sport orientation and **rogaining** (which is for the moment, too extremal for me). So I ask, do you know, if such competitions do find place in Germany, and if so, where to find informations about them?

Example orienteering march maps:
[image: Ortophotomap Orienteering Warsaw]

[image: Orienteering Warsaw Advanced MokIno]

[image: City Orienteering Lublin]
Source: Wikipedia

Comment: I lived in Germany for a few years.  Do you mean 'Volksmarch'?

Comment: No, I mean something like this: http://stowarzysze.om.pttk.pl/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/protokol_nbmno_2013.pdf (see maps in PDF))

Answer (score 6):

What you mean is called "Orientierungslauf" or in short "OL" in Germany. There are some events, but it is best you get in touch with some organizers over there perhaps using this [list of upcoming orienteering marches](http://www.orientierungslauf.de/3/1?jahr=2013&monat=04&disziplin=&art=&region=Deutschland).

In my experience the events of this kind which are not highly popular are mostly not (yet) present on the internet.

It's "popular" around southern Germany, but popular is very relative.

Comment: Well no, I don't mean runs, where the time is the most important... it's very specific discipline and it's really even hard to explain what I mean ;)

Comment: is it more like a treasurehunt?

Comment: Something like puzzle with the map, see the link in my comment to the question

Answer (score -1):

I can give an answer for **Switzerland**:

[Orienteering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienteering) in Switzerland is comparatively popular and widely known  - and also called "OL/Orientierungslauf" (incidentally, Switzerland is also [rather good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienteering#World_rankings) at this in competitions).

I don't know how prevalent this is, but in my childhood orienteering was one of the subjects taught in physical education/sports during primary and secondary school - i.e. all of us kids got to team up in groups, each group got a map and they sent us into a nearby (small) forest.

I have to say, however, that I haven't yet heard of an orienteering event that uses fragmented/obfuscated maps of the kind that you described - though that doesn't mean that it can't exist...

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question. I mean yes the Swiss sometimes get lost and invade other countries due to failures of navigation http://www.nytimes.com/2007/03/13/opinion/13iht-edstamm.4893796.html but this still doesn't answer the question which was **specific to Germany**

Comment: I don't mind the dig at us Swiss. But I added an answer, similar in structure to the one about Germany, which explains the situation in a Switzerland because they are neighbours and are both part of the German speaking region in central Europe with a lot of cultural similarities.

Comment: This really isn't going to help people coming from Google who are looking for the information.  It would be better to ask a similar question **specific to Switzerland and then put this answer there.**

Comment: I disagree. The way I see it the question was cultural one (about _popularity_) and not specifically about finding certain events located within some country borders. Thus answering for culturally related areas is IMHO valuable and valid. Also note that depending on where in Germany you are located, Switzerland might well be a lot closer/faster to reach than, say, North Germany.

Comment: @fgysin - if you could add in information about similarities between the two countries OL events, that could help. However in reading the OPs comments on Jeredepp's answer, it doesn't sound like OL is what they mean anyway.